# Compatibility on Acer Swift 3 SF314-51

Tags: laptop

I'm looking to buy a new laptop and I'm stunned from the design and performance of Elementary OS.

Looking for laptop, I found the Acer Swift 3 SF314-51 (for a price below 900 EUR), and before buying it, I would really like to know if Linux is supported. Would love to hear from someone that already has it.

In alternative, my other options (if Elementary OS generally goes ok with them) are:

- Dell Inspiron 13
- Lenovo Yoga 710
- New thinkpad 13? Or others good Lenovo?
- HP Envy 13
- Asus zenbook?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check any Lenovo option you're considering. There are dozens of topics like this one on Lenovo forums (it's not even Linux specific): https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-710-Constant-Fan-Noise-even-when-idle/td-p/3354501

I just got Lenovo 510s-13IKB (i5-7200U, 8GB, 256GB SSD). Upgraded the kernel to the latest stable (4.9.11), because of the Kaby Lake CPU, but I guess Loki with the latest HWE stack should work just as fine. Everything works, keyboard backlight, all the Fn keys. Just the problem with the constant fan noise.
My 3 year old Asus is way more quiet than the new Lenovo :(

Comment: The Lenovo you bought was one of the options I thought, but the noise is really bad for University. I'm Sorry for that, and will search another option! Maybe new thinkpad13, or Asus zenbook are best?

Comment: I have no experience with Thinkpad13 nor Zenbook. There are solution for this problem, and when I get the time I'll try to make Notebook Fan Control work (https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc). There's also Yoga Fan Control (https://github.com/blan4/lenovo-yoga-fan-control). Also, since the BIOS update is only for Windows (it's not self-extracting exe), I'm not even able to update BIOS :(